# Stitch facets in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have 2 data sets I'd like to `ggplot` side by side so they share the `y-axis`.

I thought of using `ggplot`'s `facet_wrap` for this but ned to find out how to `stitch` them together. This is what I have so far:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(x=c(-0.678071905112638,1.32192809488736,-0.678071905112638,1.32192809488736,-0.678071905112638,1.32192809488736),
                   y=c(62.8805462356349,73.027603062927,88.4090942806369,87.6879626013305,55.9895740872068,93.5396099910227),
                   side=1,stringsAsFactors = F)

df.2 <- data.frame(x=c(1.32192809488736,3.32192809488736,1.32192809488736,1.32192809488736),
                   y=c(73.027603062927,7.33717302418609,87.6879626013305,93.5396099910227),
                   side=2,stringsAsFactors = F)

df <- rbind(df.1,df.2)
df$side <- factor(df$side,levels=c(1,2))

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~side,ncol=2,scales="free")+stat_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~x,colour="black")+theme(strip.text.y=element_text())
```

[image]

How do I get rid of the y-axis of the right facet and remove the space between the facets so they appear as a single figure? Also, they need to have the same y-axis coordinates.

To be clear, the reason I'm using two `facets` is because I'm fitting an lm to each `df` separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adjust the margin between the facets to remove the space. Also, use `scales="free_x"` so that only the x-axis scales will be free, while the y-axis scales will be the same. Because the y-axis scales are the same in each facet, the scale won't be repeated on the right facet:

```
theme_set(cowplot::theme_cowplot()) 

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~side, ncol=2, scales="free_x") + 
  stat_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~x, colour="black") + 
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(-1.25, "lines"))
```

[image]

But you could also avoid facetting and get separate lines using a color aesthetic. This approach puts everything on a single panel, so you don't have to worry about lining up the x-scales between facets:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~x, aes(colour=side))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the y limits with `ylim`. Adjust the gap with `panel.spacing.x`. Remove the unwanted labels with `axis.text.y` and the tick marks with `axis.ticks`.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()+ ylim(0, 120) +
         facet_wrap(~side,ncol=2,scales="free")+
        stat_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~x,colour="black")+
        theme(strip.text.y=element_text(),  axis.text.y = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(), panel.spacing.x=unit(0, "lines"))
```

[image]